# In Image Uploading getting "First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object" in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, orientation

I am using fixorientation node module, in that I am uploading my local image to  fixOrientation function. It throwing the error "First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object". What I am doing wrong?. How to fix this. Following this doc:https://www.npmjs.com/package/fix-orientation

Folder structure

nodeapp

- app.js
- package.json
- test.jpeg
- node_modules

app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
http = require('http'),
path = require('path'),
app = express(),
server = http.createServer(app);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));
app.listen(3000);
global.atob = require("atob");
var fixOrientation = require('fix-orientation');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
// var url = '/D:/node/orio/test.jpg';

fixOrientation('test.jpg', { image: true }, function (fixed, image) {
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = fixed;
 document.body.appendChild(img);
 document.body.appendChild(image);
 });
})
```

Comment: For one thing, check that the suffix matches: `test.jpeg` or `test.jpg`?

Comment: @mtkopone thanks for quick response.   I tried Both.

Comment: Turns out fix-orientation is supposed to be used in the browser, with a data-url as the image content (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs). If you want a server-based solution, I suggest searching npm.